# Packaged App: syncFileSystem / fileSystem API - For *large* files

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am looking to develop a Chrome Packaged App that will (at a very simple level) provide a dynamic form filling UI - but allow users to attach large attachments to the forms (could be upwards of 10 files of 10MB each). I would like to have the ability to save and share the form data and the attachment via Google Drive. The forms will be completed collaboratively by multiple team members who also need to all see the attachments. Imagine a form front-end/metadata that sits on top of a shared Google Drive folder...

I have read the documentation, and learnt that the syncFileSystem API is not intended for use for general and/or large files to be stored in Google Drive, but rather for small configuration data.

I then looked at the fileSytem API - hoping that I could include the Sandboxed folder for the app in the folders that the Google Drive Client App (so that the files get synced automatically)  - but it doesn't look like the sandbox is meant to be accessed externally.

My current thinking is to recreate a windows explorer type UI in the packaged app (can use drag and drop) - then store the files in the sandbox using the fileSystem API. I can reuse the code from the Google Drive sample packaged app to implement cloud syncing.  Good idea?

Two questions stem from this:

- How persistent is the fileSystem API. The documentation mentions that the user can purge all stored files - is this done through 'clearing all browser history' ? In which case they could very easily accidentally wipe many hundreds of MB of useful information that I am storing in the packaged app.
- I have read that you can use a 3rd party authentication services (which I want to do). If I use a non-Google account to authenticate my users, how would the Google Drive authentication work ? Would I be able to use a different Google account to perform the cloud storage (i.e. unrelated to the actual end user, who may or may not have a Google account already - which may already be signed in)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like waiting for this https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=148486 (getting read access to non-sandbox directories) would be the easiest way forward.

I don't think clearing browser history deletes temporary sandbox filesystem files, they're supposed to be sort of automatically garbage collected when space is required. It would make sense if that were another checkbox in the "Clear browsing data" section of chrome's options. Perhaps that would make the answer to your first question more clear :-)

The second point, I am not sure how to do this, but it looks like you have already figured out something? At least that's what this page https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/hOYu75Cv0AE seems to indicate